# Need help for construct DLSQ-spline in $B$-form

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces, spline

In *Schumaker, Larry L. "Computing bivariate splines in scattered data fitting and the finite-element method." Numerical Algorithms 48.1-3 (2008): 237-260* ([Link to journal](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-008-9175-x), [link to author page for PDF](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schumake/numeralg.pdf)), Section 5, the authors claim that

> It follows from standard Hilbert space approximation results that
>   there exists a unique DLSQ-spline $s_l$ which is characterized by the
>   property $$<s_l−f, \psi>_A=0,\quad \forall \psi\in S(\bigtriangleup)$$

I Know that every Polynomial spline $s$ can be presented in $B$-form (Bezier-Bernestein Form) that exists a $\{c_\xi\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$s = \sum_{|\xi|=d} c_\xi B_\xi^d.$$
In this case is **standard Hilbert space approximation results** like Galerkin methods ([link to Galerkin wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method)) in numerical analysis? What is "**standard Hilbert space approximation results**" around this content?

Any guide is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On section 4 of *Von Golitschek, Manfred, Ming-Jun Lai, and Larry L. Schumaker. Error bounds for minimal energy bivariate polynomial splines. Numer. Math (1999)*, authors show that problem of finding a spline with minimal energy surface can formulated into a standard approximation problem in Hilbert space. For DLSQ splines also we can follow their attitude.

Thus it is not Galerkin method like and the expression "**standard Hilbert space approximation results**" refers to converted problem into Hilbert space literature.